# <div> contents not updating on jquery output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I have this div: `<div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>`.

The text content is meant to change as the inputs on:

`<input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">`

and

`<input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">`

are updated. This doesn't work and I cannot see why? The `<script>` should do this, but it is not parsing through?

Any help would be much appreciated please :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});
var repayment = function() {

};
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = function() {
    $('#years').html(this.value + ' years');
  };
  makeSomething();
};

function makeSomething() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[2];
    var repaymentCell = $row.find('td').last()
    var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
    var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
    $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  });
}
$("#myForm :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;
  return {
    repayment: repayment.toFixed(2),
    loantovalue: loantovalue,
    year: year
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />2yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />3yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" />5yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t9" id="t9" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<form name="repaymentcalc" id="myForm" action="">
  </br>
  <p>
    Home Value £
    <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  <p>
    Loan Amount £
    <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  Term
  <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">

  <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years</div>

  <p>

    <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

    </div>
</form>

<br>

<div id="mortgagediv">
  <table id="mortgagetable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="productheader">
        <th class="lender">Lender</th>
        <th class="type">Type</th>
        <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
        <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
        <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
        <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
        <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
        <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When `loanamount` changes, an empty function is called. When `numberpayments` is changed, the "years" div is updated. I don't see any code attempting to update the `ltv` div.

Comment: This code is a mess - mixture of vanilla javascript & jquery. Empty function where you think the behaviour should take place etc etc. This is not so much "whats wrong with this code" as its "youre going to need to completely rewrite my code"

Comment: You know what: I took a look at **all** your code and there is nowhere the text content of that div is updated. I expected to see something like `$("#ltv").text(newValue)`

Comment: How could the `div`'s content change if you are not evey trying to change it. It's not that it doesn't work, you are missing that code. "There `script` should do this", tell us where it should do it? Please read your code before asking the question. The code is working as expected.

Comment: Wow. I didn't ask anyone to completely rewrite my code at all. I simply asked for any help. I can see what is wrong now, I simply missed this when I copied code across from an earlier project. Sorry I am not as advanced a coder as you, but everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working as expected, you are missing the code where you update `#ltv`'s content. Take a look at the snippet I included, I wrote a comment about the statement that should be included for the `#ltv` element to update its content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});
var repayment = function() {

};
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = function() {
    $('#years').html(this.value + ' years');
  };
  makeSomething();
};

function makeSomething() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[2];
    var repaymentCell = $row.find('td').last()
    var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
    var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
    $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  });
}
$("#myForm :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  /* Add this line below, adjust toFixed(n) 
   * where n is the number of decimals you want to show 
   */
  $('#ltv').text('Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(2) + '%');

  var year = z / 12;
  return {
    repayment: repayment.toFixed(2),
    loantovalue: loantovalue,
    year: year
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />2yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />3yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" />5yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t9" id="t9" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<form name="repaymentcalc" id="myForm" action="">
  </br>
  <p>
    Home Value £
    <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  <p>
    Loan Amount £
    <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  Term
  <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">

  <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years</div>

  <p>

    <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

    </div>
</form>

<br>

<div id="mortgagediv">
  <table id="mortgagetable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="productheader">
        <th class="lender">Lender</th>
        <th class="type">Type</th>
        <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
        <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
        <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
        <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
        <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
        <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```